# NSMergeConflict with newVersion = <deleted>

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

After spending a lot of hours with this error I come here to ask if somebody have some information about this error. I load two entities, a Parks entity and a GuidedTour entity. A Paks can be relatet to many GuidedTours but when I try to save it, the error raises:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "(null)" UserInfo={conflictList=(
>       "NSMergeConflict (0x17026afc0) for NSManagedObject (0x1740d94b0) with objectID '0xd000000000240002 ' with oldVersion = 0 and newVersion =  and old cached row = {\n    language = \"de_DE\";\n  text = \"Apapapapapa"...}

I can't understand what is wrong, my Merge policy is: NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType

And my code:

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

```
NSError *error = nil;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"GuidedTours" inManagedObjectContext:self.context ];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.context  executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guided_tours_parks == NULL"];
fetchedObjects = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

GuidedTours *tour = [fetchedObjects firstObject];



fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entityPark = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parks" inManagedObjectContext:self.context ];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityPark];

fetchedObjects = [self.context  executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",[jsonData objectForKey:@"Park ID"] ];
fetchedObjects = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Parks *park = [fetchedObjects firstObject];


[tour setGuided_tours_parks:park];

[park addParks_guided_toursObject:tour];



// Save the object to persistent store
if (![self.context  save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Does somebody have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same error, and in my case it occurred on inserts after attempting to perform an `NSBatchDeleteRequest`. The problem was that after performing the `NSBatchDeleteRequest`, I was not calling the `[self.context reset]` method.

As per a WWDC 2015 talk, batch updates/deletions circumvent the context and directly modify the persistent store file. Thus, if you do not call `reset`, your context will contain deleted objects which can cause the above merge conflict you experienced.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/220/

Comment: "batch updates/deletions circumvent the context" - important to know!